# How do I copy and paste text between applications?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, text-editor

Very often I find myself wishing that I could copy text from a tweet I am reading (in the Twitter app) and paste it in, for example, TweetDeck so I can retweet/reply. How do I go about doing this? Prolonged touch does not work in this case, as it does in the E-mail apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outside of email and the browser, you can only copy text from editable text fields, so you can't directly copy text from other people's tweets in the Twitter app.

### Workaround:

Install [Copy to Clipboard](http://www.appbrain.com/app/copy-to-clipboard/se.johanhil.clipboard) from the Market. This integrates with the 'Share' menu. By sharing a tweet to this app it will copy the text to you clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste.